# Removing a custom attribute in Magento via an installer script

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the following code in an installer script & need to now remove the is_school attribute via the installer script, is my code correct?

```
// code within existing installer script (this works fine)
$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_school",  array(
"type"     => "int",
"backend"  => "",
"label"    => "Is School?",
"input"    => "int",
"source"   => "",
"visible"  => false,
"required" => false,
"default" => "",
"frontend" => "",
"unique"     => false,
"note"       => ""
));
```

My intended approach to remove the attribute - does this look correct?

```
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->removeAttribute('customer', 'is_school');
$installer->endSetup();
```

Is there anything else required when removing attributes?

Comment: If `$installer` is an instance of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` and `customer` was the only entity where `is_school` was added, your remove script should work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$custAttr = 'is_school'; 

 $setup->removeAttribute('customer', $custAttr);
 $setup->endSetup();
```

Please check `class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`

In

```
public function removeAttribute($entityTypeId, $code)
{
    $mainTable  = $this->getTable('eav/attribute');
    $attribute  = $this->getAttribute($entityTypeId, $code);
    if ($attribute) {
        $this->deleteTableRow('eav/attribute', 'attribute_id', $attribute['attribute_id']);
        if (isset($this->_setupCache[$mainTable][$attribute['entity_type_id']][$attribute['attribute_code']])) {
            unset($this->_setupCache[$mainTable][$attribute['entity_type_id']][$attribute['attribute_code']]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

It takes two arguments - the first is the `entity code`, and the second is the `attribute code`.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to create a different upgrade script. If the install script's version is 0.1.0 then create the file upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php and add the following content in it.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->removeAttribute('customer', 'is_school');
$installer->endSetup();
```

Then go to config.xml and change the version tag from 0.1.0 to 0.1.1.

Clear the cache and refresh any page.