# Remove custom attribute from sales/quote in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to remove a custom attribute in Magento, the following code adds the attribute I just need the equivalent to remove using the Magento installer scripts:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_school",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "is_school?",
    "input"    => "int",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => false,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
));

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote'), 'is_school', 'int(11)');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'is_school', 'int(11)');

// need code to remove these two column above

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing a custom attribute in Magento via an installer script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775867/removing-a-custom-attribute-in-magento-via-an-installer-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Magento class::method for this is `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::removeAttribute()`.

So, your installer/update script would contain something like the following:

```
$installer->removeAttribute("customer", "is_school");
```

Hope that helps.